# nginx rewrite rule to replace .php endings with /

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite

Basically, I want the ".php" to be replaced with a "/". I tried to just put my rule in the same location where the fastcgi is located.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                rewrite ^(.+)\.php$ /$1;
}
```

However, when I restart nginx with these settings, it gives me an 500 Internal Server Error and I can't even get the server to show me anything. Is this because of fast cgi? How can I work around this?

My system: nginx / php5-fpm / apc / php5-memcache / Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  If you rewrite the URL from `foo.php` to `/foo` (you say you want .php replaced with "/" but your rewrite has the slash on the wrong side of $1), then PHP will try to execute `/foo` which probably does not exist.  Moving the slash to the end means PHP will try to execute `foo/` which still won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your info DerfK. I want  foo.php to become foo/. Are you saying this is not even possible?

Comment: What do you mean "become"?  You want people to click on a link that says "foo/" and foo.php is executed?

Comment: Yes, and I don't want to have any .php in the address bar because I want to create a clean URL such as the one here in serverfault without any endings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, your general plan has a lot of problems with it.  First, since you are removing the .php, the rewrite has to be outside of `location ~ .php$` since the URL won't end in .php until *after* it is rewritten.   Second, your `rewrite` is backwards.  You want the URL `http://www.example.com/foo/` to run `foo.php`, so the rewrite would need to be

```
rewrite ^(.+)/ $1.php;
```

But this means that EVERY directory on your website would need a matching .php file since you will no longer be able to use index.php automatically.  Also, if nginx does not de-duplicate slashes before rewriting, if someone mistypes an address as `http://www.example.com/foo//` then it will execute `/foo/.php`.

Finally, how many PHP files are you planning on creating?  Do you really think serverfault has a 304162.php file for this question? (not that serverfaults' URL would match your rewrite since it doesn't end in `/`, nor do they use PHP I think)

Normally, clean URLs work by declaring a specific location (for instance `/questions/`) then rewriting everything AFTER that URL to be run by a single script:

```
rewrite ^/questions/(.*)$ /questions.php?path=$1 last;
```

You could also do something like

```
rewrite ^/questions/([0-9]+)(/.*)?$ /questions.php?qid=$1&extra=$2 last;
```

So that URLs could be `example.com/questions/1` `example.com/questions/1/` `example.com/questions/1/how-do-I-rewrite` but `example.com/questions/banana` would be rejected for not having a numeric question id.

Take a look at how people set up clean URLs for [Drupal](http://hostingfu.com/article/running-drupal-with-clean-url-on-nginx-or-lighttpd) or [Wordpress](http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-nginx-rewrite-rules/).  Essentially, every request for a file that does not exist is rewritten as `/index.php?q=$1`, where index.php looks at the "q" variable to figure out what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Just short FYI, you don't actually need the q parameter for Wordpress, you can just rewrite to /index.php and Wordpress will do just fine.